# How can a template class inherit from a nested template class

Tags: c++, templates, nested

Consider the following code :

```
template<class C, class P>
//class Cchild : public C::NestedClass              // Works
class Cchild : public C::NestedTemplateClass<P>     // Fails : how to inherit from nested template class defined in C ?
{
};
```

Compiler compiles fine when template class `Cchild` inherits from a nested class `C::NestedClass` . However, it fails to compile if I want `Cchild` to inherit from a nested template class `C::NestedTemplateClass<P>`

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is:

```
template<class C, class P>
class Cchild : public C::template NestedTemplateClass<P>
{
};
```

The error message from gcc was actually quite readable:

```
t.C:3:26: error: non-template ‘NestedTemplateClass’ used as template
 class Cchild : public C::NestedTemplateClass<P>
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
t.C:3:26: note: use ‘C::template NestedTemplateClass’ to indicate that it is a template
```

Comment: I though having tried this syntax, but apparently not. And yes, if I was using `gcc` instead of `vc`, I'll probably get the answer in the error message. Thanks Sam.